# position: fixed not referring parent relative left position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have did one example: on scroll down, RHS panel on floating when scroll bar reach the RHS panel header.

http://www.elankeeran.com/test/RHSpanel.htm

But while scroll down RHS panel jump to off screen; I don't why position fixed not referring parent relative position left. it referring body left position.

after changing below css its working fine

```
#floating-box{position: absolute;width:100%;width:960px; margin:0 auto;}
```

if anyone known better solution please let me know.

Comment: use position absolute instead of position fixed because fixed refer to the window screen

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked *why* this is happening, see the definition of `position : fixed` in [the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning), notably that

> for a fixed positioned box, the containing block is established by the
>   viewport.

Or, as [another site](http://www.cssbasics.com/chapter_17_css_position.html) puts it,

```
the parent element is always the browser window
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var wHeight = $(window).height();
$('.right-panel').css("height",wHeight-80);
if ( scrollY > bodyY && isfixed ) {
 $floatingbox.stop().css({
position: 'fixed',
    // left: wLeft,
top: 10
```

## remove the !isfixed and make it isfixed

Comment: @elankeeran will u elaborate coz it worked i copied ur code and tried!

Comment: var isfixed = $floatingbox.css('position') == 'fixed';  ur isfixed is  set to fixed hence the if block will never work..thats what is giving the problem..